# How to fetch only branch names from remote git repo?

Tags: git

How can I get remote refs list (only names and commit id) without fetching objects?

WebUI is not answer obviously.

All that I found is remote `HEAD` name:

```
$ git remote -v show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git.git
  Push  URL: https://git.git
  HEAD branch: main
  Remote branch:
    refs/remotes/origin/master stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
```

Comment: Bad wording for a question, really ... given `fetch` is an actual subcommand in Git ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L I was using `git fetch --depth 1` before that answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git ls-remote origin`:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558        HEAD
ebf3c04b262aa27fbb97f8a0156c2347fecafafb        refs/heads/maint
670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558        refs/heads/master
670b81a890388c60b7032a4f5b879f2ece8c4558        refs/heads/next
33bc620fd1829b92a6671b6bd65ee357447aa964        refs/heads/seen
2cbe4a3e125e059242544ae415ee82452eccc15b        refs/heads/todo
```

That lists the references, including branches and tags.  If you want only branches, you can restrict it to things matching `refs/heads`: `git ls-remote origin | grep refs/heads`.

Comment: `git ls-remote --heads origin`.

Comment: @bk2204 it accepts `[<repository> [<refs>...]]` where `refs` is a glob pattern, so no need for grep